# how to set inner text margin of button

Tags: wpf, text, button, padding, margin

I have a WPF button with some text in it. If I don't set button's width manually, then the button width will be almost of text's width, and it doesn't look very good. I don't want to calculate the width of each button. Is there a more convenient way to specify the relative width of the button? For example in CSS you can specify padding or margin. Is there something like that in WPF?

Comment: So you have a button, and you know you want something like padding or margin... Did you look to see if those properties exist on the button?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can set the Button's `Padding`

```
<Button Content="Test" Padding="5,2" />
```